# Default program startup display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have a dual display setup and would like to be able to set which display a piece of software starts on.  Most software seems to return to the last display but Stellarium always starts in the primary display. Does Linux have a way of forcing the startup display or is it something the individual program has to manage?

Thanks.

EDIT

And with no changes on my part Stellarium is behaving nicely and remembering which screen it was on.  Still nice to know if there is a way of forcing this.